# Prevent automatic resize of window when content changes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have made a picture viewer which is a `Window` with `SizeToContent="Width"`. This looks just the way I want it when I open it with the first picture in a series.

When I go the next picture in the series, which happens to be wider than the previous one, the `Window` is resized to fit this new picture. The left edge of the `Window` stays in the same place, but the right edge of the `Window` is now outside the edge of the screen.

How can I prevent an automatic resize like this?

I do not want to use `ResizeMode="NoResize"` because I want the user to be able to manually change the size of the `Window` should he or she want to.

**XAML**

```
<Window SizeToContent="Width" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                    Content="Previous" />
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                    Content="Next" />
            <Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage}" 
                   Stretch="Uniform" 
                   StretchDirection="DownOnly" 
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Remove `SizeToContent="Width"`.  Perhaps your real question is, "I am sizing my window to content because [list reasons]. This sucks because the window keeps resizing as I show different images.  Here's my XAML [blat]. How can I achieve [reasons] without this unwanted behavior?"

Comment: If I remove `SizeToContent` the window is always too large. I want the window to be sized so that the first image is displayed correctly, then never resized again (unless by user interaction). `SizeToContent` does the first one beautifully.

Comment: @GTHvidsten if that's the case, you could through code get the width of the first image and apply that to the window on startup

Comment: Well, it's a bit hacky, but you could add an event handler to the Loaded event of the Image control, check to see how wide the image is, then resize the main window's width to the image's width.  At the end of the event handler I'd unsubscribe from the event so it never executes again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset the SizeToContent property in a Loaded event handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (o, e) => SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
}
```

Or if you don't like code behind:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="SizeToContent">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static SizeToContent.Manual}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: This seems to work as I intended. Of course, I now have other size issues with my sizes, but they're not related to this. Thanks.