# Prevent window resize when the content of a Qt window changes

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

How can I prevent a QML window from changing size when the content was updated? In particular, I'm loading a picture into a an `Image` element. When the picture is changed, the window should keep its size instead of resizing the the picture's dimensions plus UI.

The user should still be able to update the window's dimensions. However, the window size should not change on its own.

This question is related to [Prevent automatic resize of window when content changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358687/prevent-automatic-resize-of-window-when-content-changes) but I'm looking to achieve this using **Pyside / QML**.

**Affected code:**

`main.qml` (Extracts)

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
ApplicationWindow {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Image {
            id: image
            source: ui.getCurrentImage()
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            clip: true
            autoTransform: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.maximumHeight: sourceSize.height
            Layout.maximumWidth: sourceSize.width
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        }
    }
```

`ui.py`

```py
def setCurrentImage(self, new_image):
        self.currentImage = new_image
        w, h = self.root.width(), self.root.height()  # Save previous window geometry
        self.imageChangedSignal.emit()  # This loads the picture and displays it, unfortunately resizing the window
        self.root.resize(w,h)  # Programatically restore the window geometry prior to the load to avoid huge window
```

Comment: I would prefer [mcve] instead. Not all people want to go this way ... git clone ... compile ... missed dependencies ... setup etc.

Comment: Note that what folibis asked is not only preferred, but also mandatory: questions should **always** be self-contained and shall not rely on external resources, which is even more important when dealing with repositories, since their contents may change in the future thus making the question invalid and useless to anybody else that could face a problem similar to yours. We don't need the full code, but a code that allows us to properly *reproduce* the problem while being short enough to allow us to focus on the problem without being distracted by aspects that are not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While this problem occurs with Qt 5 / Pyside 2, it is completely resolved by upgrading to Qt 6.5 and Pyside 6.5. Even the workaround is no longer needed - the window is no longer resized when the content changes.